# Spring Boot to Spring XD conversion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-xd

I have an existing stand-alone Spring Boot (CommandLineRunner) application that generates JSON payloads, currently written to the local file system.  Though I could tail that file easily in Spring XD, I'd rather have the entire Spring Boot application run as either a source or job module in Spring XD, but I'm having some difficulties making the conversion.  Does anyone know of a Spring XD sample where the XD module (source or job) is the creator/originator of outgoing messages, instead of using some sort of inbound adapter from another external system?  (Maybe my entire premise is misguided, but I want the application to be managed by Spring XD so that I don't have to manage another out-of-band orchestration tool to start and stop the JSON-generating process.)

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question. But you may look into the directory xd/modules/source/time/config/time.xml. In this configuration the messages are generated using the java.util.Date class and a SimpleDateFormat. Instead of referencing these two classes, you could call a method on the service class that generates your json.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward that example - I had overlooked it and it definitely helped.